# Apache 2.4.12 using virtual host on /var/www/drupal

Tags: apache2, drupal

I'm trying to run a virtual host for drupal and having trouble setting it's root files.

I have a file **drupalDev.conf** in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/** configured:

```
    ServerName drupaltest
    DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal
```

This is the only enabled site.

In `var/www/drupal` I have all drupal files, including `install.php`. Accessing `http://drupaltest` returns the `/var/www/html/index.html` which apache uses by default. Accessing `http://drupaltest/install.php` returns 404.

How can I tell the server to use the files within `/var/www/drupal` ?

### Other settings:

**/etc/hosts** is set:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   drupaltest
```

**/etc/appache2/appache2.conf** is set:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Note:** I've tried setting `000-default.conf` to `DocumentRoot /var/www` but nothing changed.
**Note:** Below you'll find my initial `drupalDev.conf` settings:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName drupaltest

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps, it will solve your problem-

**1. create a file `drupalDev.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`**

> `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/drupalDev.conf`

**2. Paste following code in `drupalDev.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal
        ServerName drupaltest
        ServerAlias drupaltest
        ServerAdmin admin@drupaltest

        <Directory /var/www/drupal/>
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**3. Run following command to enable `drupalDev.conf`**

> `sudo a2ensite drupalDev.conf`

**4. Restart `apache2 service`**

> `sudo service apache2 restart`

**5. Browse new created host domain in browser**

> `http://drupaltest`

**Note :**  You may need to change file permission of `/var/www/drupal` to `777`

> `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/drupal`

Comment: It worked thanks. had to erase everything from drupalDev.conf and paste what you wrote. I will edit my question and write all the code from my initial drupalDev.conf file that didn't work. Can you briefly explain what changes made it work and why?

Comment: Did you perform `Step 3 & 4` with your previous `drupalDev.conf` ?

Comment: Also there is `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` tags navigating to root folder is missing in your `VirtualHost`. This tells the server, which directory is to navigate on visiting `http://drupaltest`

Comment: Yes, I did perform steps 3 and 4, only instead of restart I ran reload. Thanks for the insight.